# correlation matrix and statistics for all numerical columns in SAS

Tags: matrix, statistics, sas, correlation

I have a data set with the name final_data which has numerical fields and some string fields. what i want to do is this

Print out a correlation matrix between all numeric variables in the data set and Compute the mean, min, max and number of missing for all the numeric variables in the data

Now i know how to calculate mean min and max by specifying the variables explicitly but i have no clue how to do it for numerical values. Also i dont know how to calculate number of missing values. As for correlation matrix between all numerical fields, i have no clue how to do that.

PS for column names u may use `num1` `num2` `str1` `str2` so on for numerical and string columns respectively.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? Try `proc corr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statistical procedures usually act on all numeric variables, so you actually don't need to specify them, e.g.:

```
proc corr data=sashelp.prdsale;
run;

proc means data=sashelp.prdsale mean min max nmiss;
run;
```

Comment: Also, the automatic variable lists _numeric_ _character_ and _all_ will let you operate on just numeric, char or all variables if desired.  In this case he doesn't need to use them but there are cases where it is nice to know about these variable lists.